# Orange Pi Zero не может определить i2c экран

Tags: orange-pi

проблема полностью описана в заголовке.

```
frozyeah@pi:~$ sudo i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

frozyeah@pi:~$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Пины настроил верно, перемычки работают.

UPD Распиновка [image: Распиновка]

Сам экран
[image: Экран]

Ну и Pi Zero
[image: OPI Zero]

Пока что буквально на костылях, но проверить нужно.

Comment: Фотки монтажа давайте

Comment: Экран точно на 3.3 вольта?

Comment: Да, как указано на странице товара на Али. Хотя я брал двухцветный, сейчас проверю с 5 вольт.

Comment: Нет, опять безрезультатно.

Comment: Ничоси! Так и спалить девайс недолго!

Answer (score 2):

Подключил сегодня без проблем на Orange Pi Zero с armbian.

Проверяем наличие устройства /dev/u2c-0, если нет - включить через

```
$ sudo armbian-config.
```

В debian или raspbian это устройство включается через

```
$ sunxi-tools.
```

Устанавливаем i2c-tools для сканера интерфейса i2cdetect.

Потом подключаем экран, запитывая от 3.3V на GPIO.

Адрес у моего экрана был 0x3c.

После всего установил python-библиотеку luma.oled и испытал примерами разработчика библиотеки - все работает

Answer (score 1):

Надо пошевелить проводами и получше воткнуть. Провода очень плохо закрепляются. Долго не мог понять, почему не определяет. Пересобрал на стенде - определилось.

Устанавливаем i2ctools:

```
sudo apt install i2c-tools
```

Детектим:

```
sudo i2cdetect -l
```

и

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 2
```

Появится регистр 3c или 0x3c.
Если не появился, попробуй другие каналы i2cdetect -y